# 404 not found when sending post request to controller

Tags: javascript, php, model-view-controller

I am calling a controller name batch_processor with the method parseFile defined.

I have a script as:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#xmlfile').multi();
});

let parseFile = (update) => {
    var xml = $('#xmlfile').val() || [],
    payload = {xmlfiles: xml};
    if(update) {
        payload['update'] = 'y';
    }
    $.post('/batch_processor/parseFile/1', payload, 
        function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#xml').val(res.xml);
            $('#parsed').val(JSON.stringify(res.parsed, null, '\t'));
            $('#manifest').val(JSON.stringify(res.manifest, null, '\t'));
            $('#report').val(JSON.stringify(res.report, null, '\t'));
        }
    );
};
```

So, when ParseFile Button is clicked this script is invoked. I have defined parseFile method inside batch_processor controller. Still I am getting [image: console message]

Comment: Now, what is your question? Please don't say, that you've no clue what 404 error from your server means ...

Comment: check if the url is correct. If your backend is on different server and url is correct then check your web server, if it is running or not.

Comment: 1. Check if you have controller and member functions names correct.
2. There must a routing mechanism in your MVC architecture. Check if that is re-writing correctly. 
3. Check your .htaccess with respect to your project.

Comment: *"I have defined parseFile method inside batch_processor controller"* - that would be the snippet you should post here.

Answer (score 0):

404 means the resource you are trying to access on server doesnt not exists

Answer (score 0):

Why is there the "/1" in your url ? I think you can try to remove them. try again

Answer (score 0):

check whether you have defined the parameter in function **(parseFile($file_id))**. For that check the same without parameter**(/batch_processor/parseFile)** . If it is working then it can be the issue with parameter.
If that doesn't work check whether you have defined **htaccess** to avoid **index.php** from url. if not add it.

Answer (score 0):

[Error 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) is thrown when URL you are trying to send your data to doesn't exist.

Check if `/batch_processor/parseFile/1` doesn't have any typo in it (I can see mixed naming conventions - maybe that is it?) and if it has valid route to proper controller.